# Nested Loops and Rolling Dice

Tags: java

I was assigned a project in which I need to make a program, making use of nested loops, that takes user input on how many sides a certain pair of dice has and how many times you roll it. The program should then calculate the probability of rolling certain number combinations. The program is somewhat simple because it gives you all of the code, you just need to put it in the correct order. I've been working at this foir a few days now but I haven't seemed to be able to make it work. Here's what I have for code:

```
/**
* This program roll a dice with a selected amount of sides a selected amount of times.
*
* Timothy Pierce
* 1/5/2016
*
*/
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
class DiceProbability
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
      //Initalizing variables
      int numRolls = 0;
      int numSides = 0;
      int match = 0;
      int sum = 0;

      //Accepting User Input
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Please enter the number of rolls: ");
      numRolls = in.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Please enter the number of sides on a dice: ");
      numSides = in.nextInt();
      System.out.print("\n Sum of Dice \t Probability \n");

      //Begin Loops
      for(int roll = 0; roll < numRolls; roll++)
      {
          for(sum = 2; sum <= (numSides*2); sum++)
          {
              int die1 = 0;
              int die2 = 0;
              Random randNum = new Random();
              die1 = randNum.nextInt(numSides)+1;
              die2 = randNum.nextInt(numSides)+1;
              if(die1 + die2 == sum)
              {
                  match = 0;
                  match++;
              }
              double probability = 0.0;
              probability = (double)match / numRolls * 100;
              System.out.println("     " + sum + "\t\t" + probability);
          }
      }
  }//End Method
}//End Class
```

All of the code is there, it is just simply not in the right order. The format of the output should be: Line asking for the number of rolls, line asking for the number of sides, Line with header that has one column for sum of dice and another for probability, and then the loops should "roll the dice" and predict the probability for each number. IE it will have two columns: one for sum, another for probability. It should then go down in order by 2,3,4,5,6 etc.with the corresponding probability in the next column directly beside it. All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the point of `match = 0; match++;`?

Comment: @shmosel it goes into the calculation of the probability and it's the number of times the sum of the dice matches the current sum

Answer (score 0):

maybe there is something wrong wiht your code， not just the order.So I try to write another one, try it.

```
/**
* This program roll a dice with a selected amount of sides a selected amount of times.
*
* Fergus Wang
* 1/6/2016
*
*/
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
class DiceProbability
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
      //Initalizing variables
      int numRolls = 0;
      int numSides = 0;
      int match = 0;
      int sum = 0;

      //Accepting User Input
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Please enter the number of rolls: ");
      numRolls = in.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Please enter the number of sides on a dice: ");
      numSides = in.nextInt();
      System.out.print("\n Sum of Dice \t Probability \n");
      // A list to save match times.
      int[] matchList = new int[numSides*2+1];
      // creat a Random tool.
      Random randNum = new Random();
      // Begin Loops
      for(int roll = 0; roll < numRolls; roll++)
      {
          int die1 = 0;
          int die2 = 0;

          die1 = randNum.nextInt(numSides)+1;
          die2 = randNum.nextInt(numSides)+1;
          int tempSum = die1 + die2;
          // check sum value.
          for(sum = 2; sum <= (numSides*2); sum++)
          {
              if(tempSum == sum)
              {
                  matchList[sum-2]++;
              }
          }
      }

      for(int index = 0; index<numSides*2-1; index++){
          double probability = 0.0;
          probability = (double)matchList[index] / numRolls * 100;
          System.out.println("     " + (index+2) + "\t\t" + probability);
      }
  }//End Method
}//End Class
```

Comment: Ops. "This program roll a dice" should be modified to "This program roll a pair of dices."

Answer (score 0):

I think the problems in your code are: The value of "die1" and "die2" must be calculated for each roll not for each loop of "sum" value. And the "match" value must be reset for every loop of the "sum" not even when `die1 + die2 == sum'. Based on the explanation i just reorder your code (didn't change any line of codes).
Here is my implementation:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
class DiceProbability
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    //Initalizing variables
    int numRolls = 0;
    int numSides = 0;
    int match = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    //Accepting User Input
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the number of rolls: ");
    numRolls = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter the number of sides on a dice: ");
    numSides = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\n Sum of Dice \t Probability \n");

    //Begin Loops
    for(int roll = 0; roll < numRolls; roll++)
    {
        int die1 = 0;
        int die2 = 0;
        Random randNum = new Random();

        die1 = randNum.nextInt(numSides)+1;
        die2 = randNum.nextInt(numSides)+1;

        for(sum = 2; sum <= (numSides*2); sum++)
        {
            match = 0;

            if(die1 + die2 == sum)
            {
                match++;
            }
            double probability = 0.0;

            probability = (double)match / numRolls * 100;
            System.out.println("     " + sum + "\t\t" + probability);
        }
    }
}//End Method
}//End Class
```

Hope this help!